# Having a place to ask questions on one's own paper

Tags: feature-request

In reference to my post:
[Alternatives to arxiv](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6584/alternatives-to-arxiv)

Jyotirmoy Bhattacharya posted:

> .
>   .
>   .
>   3. Publicise the key points: Make a newsgroup posting, or create a
>   question here or on Mathoverflow that explains your main insight or
>   innovation and link to your paper.
>
> I was a bit hesitant in writing (3)
>   since if you do it wrong you are just creating spam. No one is obliged
>   to read on if you say "I have proved X. Can you please check?". Much
>   better to say "So far people did not succeed in approach A to problem
>   B because of C. But I think things can be made to work if you do D.
>   Here's an attempt."

I think I understand why Jyotirmoy was a bit hesitant. I know people are not obliged to read others' papers. But I think maybe it will be better if it was okay to ask questions like "I have proved X. Can you please check?".

EDIT: My motivation for this comes from the fact that since I am not a math student(but CS) it would be nice, if I can have someplace to post and have random people comment on my math stuff. Because it has been hard for me to find advisors without going to the university.

Comment: Why the down votes? Isn't this a valid question/suggestion for meta?

Comment: Dear Roupam Ghosh, downvotes in this meta site mean simply that the downvoter does not agree with your proposal. (And no, there is no requirement for downvoters to explain their reasons)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you «create a question here or on Mathoverflow that explains your main insight or innovation and link to your paper» then you are, in particular, *not asking a mathematical question* —you should write that in the introduction to your paper, in fact! And adding «can you please check?» does not turn it into one, either, in my opinion. We have had several «can you please check my solution to this exercise?» questions in the past, and I don't find anything wrong with them —nor has the community, as far as I remember; but checking a solution to an exercise is considerably different to checking a paper.

If you write a paper and want feedback on it, publish it on the arXiv and —very tactfully, unimposingly and *once*— write to people who work on the subject and might be interested sending them link (I think a link is much better than the actual file: everyone hates having their Inbox filled by strangers; if you send this to several people, write to each of them *separately*: everyone hates being included in mass-email) and —again, unimposingly— tell them that you are willing to receive any comments they might have. Don't ask them to *check* your work.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I still think having a "can you please check?" type question is a good idea. And there are pros and cons to this too. So, in my opinion instead of going through pre-print servers or a forum/ask type boards, we also should have someplace where people discuss their ideas and comment on each others works. Think about it, this makes it an online version of getting advice from an advisor!!! Regards, Roupam

Comment: That «we also should have someplace where people discuss their ideas and comment on each others works» may be true, but it does not imply that it is a good idea to turn *this* site into such a place. This is *not* a discussion site, and it is designed on purpose to make dialog difficult and inconvenient.

Comment: *«Think about it, this makes it an online version of getting advice from an advisor!»* I have thought about it, and that is why I think it is a bad idea, specially when you put it in those terms!

Comment: FWIW, I agree with Mariano's last comment. If you put it in that context it very much doesn't fit with this site's policy of asking questions with definite answers and avoiding questions that can lead to protracted discussions. While I don't have an opinion on whether it is good to have "an online version of getting advice from an advisor", I do think that _this_ is not the website for that purpose.

Comment: "I do think that this is not the website for that purpose." --> Yes I also agree with that, Willie. There should be a separate site for that, not here.

Comment: (+1) I like Mariano's answer much in its contents and in its tact.